# Understanding XTS, why better than CBC with generated IVs?

Tags: security, encryption, aes

I tried to understand XTS-mode, so I did some research.

I found the following article (http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/04/30/you-dont-want-xts/).

This page raised some questions; please help me to answer those:

1. XTS does the XOR operation twice on the record (once before encryption and once after the encryption). What benefits does the second XOR give?.
2. As an alternative CBC was mentioned, would CBC be as secure as XTS when the IV would have been generated using the same method? (IV=AES_ECB(IVKEY, block offset)

   For the first sector's perspective the only difference is the additional XOR, is it?

   ```
   First Sector XTS = TWEAK ^ ( AES_ECB(key, plaintext ^ TWEAK) )
   First Sector CBC = AES_ECB(key, plaintext ^ IV )
   ```
3. XTS applies the tweak unique to each 32 byte block, no chaining like in CBC. This means that like "CTR", changes can be made bit granular?

---

CBC's chaining nature combined with the generated IVs using a secret key and the block offset seems to a better deal than XTS? Maybe I'm missing something and most likely it is linked to the second XORing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] is a better place to ask such a question. Consider splitting your three questions into separate posts.

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer to 2)

In CBC mode if an attacker knows the IV and (the key?) then can generate one garbled block and then could control the entire block. ([Reference](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5587/compare-blockmode-cbc-with-diffuser-against-xts))

Answer to 3)

CTR mode is XORing with the key expanded using the cipher, this makes it possible to flip bits.

Directly applying AES prevents bit flipping in both CBC and XTS. ([Reference](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14628/why-do-we-use-xts-over-ctr-for-disk-encryption))

As for 1), I have asked the question on Crypto.SE [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24431/what-is-the-benefir-of-applying-the-tweak-second-time-using-xts).